# Odoo: Hide one option inside a dropdown menu

Tags: odoo, dropdown, hide

I would like to hide one of the options that appears in a dropdown menu. For example, i want to hide the option "Modulos" in the dropdown "Equipo" so the user cant select it.  Is this possible? How?

Thank you in advance

[image: Dropdown menu]

Comment: This can be done with a domain expression. Can you share the xml view to see the field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add domain in your many2one dropdown field.

```
equipo = fields.Many2one('model.name', 'Equipo', domain = [('field_name','!=','Modulos')])
```